# Standard margins in iOS for info display

Tags: gui-design, android, ios, user-expectation, metrics

I've read the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH66-SW1) at least 2 times today, but I don't find what are the guidelines for spacing or margin between views.

I come from an [Android guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html) perspective where they expected spacing is written for cases like headers, text boxes, labels, and more; so I'm trying to find the relative for iOS.

Is there a documentation on that, or an article I can base my design with? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

44px is the minimum recommended size for tap areas.
[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ContentViews.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW1)

> As with all UI objects that users might want to tap, ensure that the minimum target area for each item in a collection view is 44 x 44 points.

16px is a default margin, from the screen edge, when using AutoLayout in iOS.

So I would use some derivative/combination of these to space views within your application.

It is incredibly subjective as to what is 'right'. User testing is the best feedback you can get here.

As a general rule I use 8/16/22/44/88 etc.

Comment: do you know how I can set these margins up in Sketch?